# Can I have a database table with no relation any other table?

Tags: php, sql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

Im working on a school project that requires me to create a basic database based on Olympic Games. Here is my current Relational Model View:

[relational model view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/megEG.png)

My question is, can I have my 'olympics' table sitting in my database with no relationships between any other tables?

The reason I am looking to include this is to display information about the current Olympic Games in general such as the year and location. Will this cause problems for me? I should also mention that my database only needs to contain at least four tables and is to run some basic queries. This is not a real world project but a practical for working with queries. Any other advice or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure, there's no requirement for a table to have relationships to other tables. If you decide you need them later you can add them.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks for that. I was thinking that myself. Can I ask in general does the fields included in each table look okay? I've tried breaking this down using 1NF, 2NF, and 3NF but all in all, it can get very confusing.

Comment: As mentioned - if there is no need for extra links don't add them in (yet).  Your structure seems to limit each athlete to one sport and also one medal - which is OK, but just something you can either state as a limitation or perhaps a future enhancement.

Comment: @NigelRen thats intentional. I just want to show an athlete participating in one sport e.g.; track and field. Events act as a subsport within this table e.g.; sprint, middle, long distance events. I understand that ideally my database would consist of so much more

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for your input. This is mainly a project for running queries on too. Would is be possible with my given design to create a query to find which team has won the most medals?

Comment: An in-depth analysis is a bit broad for this Q&A format, especially without knowing the specific goals of your project. As far as finding which team has the most medals, it does look like you would be able to do that.

Comment: Great @Don'tPanic thanks guys for your input. I know its very broad but I've been spending so long trying to get it right. I think I'm overthinking it at this point. Again it is a school project and I don't want to be asking for direct answers, just a bit of advice :)

Comment: If it is only for the current olympic games then wouldn't the olympics table only have one row?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a relationship hidden in there that you don't quite realize.  As you begin to track events, you will likely have an EventDate.  That date has a year in it.  And that year is related to the Year in your Olympics table

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a table with no relation to other tables.

Comment: Pretty basic answer. But it is true.